Show the value of users selected results from views exposed filter
I would like to show the value of a user-selected option similar to this question I found here: Views exposed filters - how to show "You searched for [exposed filters]" above results?
Their example, which is similar to what I'm looking for:
[ ] Cats
[x] Dogs

[Search]


You searched for Dogs

===============================
Lassie        Movie star
Bones         Runner
Hobbes        Show-dog

The problem is that the suggested module is for D7. I'm developing for D10 and am using Better Exposed Filters module. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You are essentially speaking of facets. The Facets module can help with this, though you may need a bit of customization for that specific functionality.
